# java - unit testing for REST request

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing

I have the method:

```
public HTTPResult get(String url) throws Exception{
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
            return new HTTPResult(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode().value());
        }
        catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            String responseBody = e.getCause().getMessage();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            return new HTTPResult(obj.getString("responseBody"), Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("statusCode")));
        }
    }
```

I want to do unit testing for it and i am not sure how to proceed:

```
public class MockHttpServerTest {

    private static final int PORT = 51234;
    private static final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + PORT;
    private MockHttpServer server;
    private SimpleHttpResponseProvider responseProvider;
    private HttpClient client;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        responseProvider = new SimpleHttpResponseProvider();
        server = new MockHttpServer(PORT, responseProvider);
        server.start();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
```

I am getting RED for MockHttpServer & SimpleHttpResponseProvider which should be part of org.apache.wink.client.*; which i am importing. so why do i have red ones? is there some simple way to unit test it?
HTTPResult return me response code and message.

Comment: What does the red mark say?

Comment: cannot resolve the symbol 'MockHttpServer'. i have the dependecy in the pom file: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Try doing a `mvn clean build`

Comment: Even after doing that, i dont have the option import org.apache.wink.client. - MockHttpServer is missing to be imported.

Comment: If you are using eclipse : `ctrl` + `shift` + `o` Its the short key for auto-import.

Comment: only for - SimpleHttpResponseProvider & MockHttpServer i dont have the option to do auto import. is there simple way to mock the http request?

Comment: Delete all import manually and then try the short key. Looks like `SimpleHttpResponseProvider` isn't present in the jar.